# how to hide the bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom sheet in flutter and it have a listview like:

```
new Flexible(child: new ListView(
            physics: new BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
              new Text("a"),
            ]
          )
      );
```

I want when I scroll to the top of the listview,the bottom sheet can scroll to hide when I continue to pull up, just like the listview can't scroll.

Comment: Is it a normal bottom sheet or modalBottomSheet?

Comment: modalBottomSheet

Answer (score 0):

******For Hide/Show you can use Visibility widget.******

```
Visibility(
visible: _visibiliityValue,
child:bottomSheetModel(....))
```

**OR You can use Opacity widget**

```
Opactity(
opacity:_opactiyValue,
child:bottomSheetModel(...))
```

**OR You can use a navigator. (For hide only )**

```
Navigator.pop(context); // for hiding or destroying model sheet
```